# How do I do factorials in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In PostgreSQL, I often times want to do something like find the [factorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) of 7. I can do that very simply with

```
SELECT 7!;

-- PostgreSQL is so full featured
-- it even supports a prefix-factorial
SELECT !!7;
```

Even [Excel has `FACT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fact-function-ca8588c2-15f2-41c0-8e8c-c11bd471a4f3),

```
=FACT(7)
```

How do I do that with SQL Server 2017 Enterprise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not aware of a built-in function to do this. You need to roll your own. Here is how I do it:

```
SELECT SQL#.Math_Factorial(5); -- 120
```

The **Math_Factorial** function is in the Free version of the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=db_200504) SQLCLR library (that I wrote).

**OR**

if you do not need it in function / UDF form, then it might be more efficient to do the following:

```
DECLARE @BaseNumber INT = 5,
        @Result BIGINT = 1;

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT TOP (@BaseNumber) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS [Num]
  FROM   sys.columns
  ORDER  BY Num
)
SELECT  @Result *= [Num]
FROM    cte;

SELECT @Result;
-- 120
```

Both approaches shown above take into account the "special" condition of passing in `0` as the "BaseNumber" and it returning `1` instead of `0`.

```
SELECT SQL#.Math_Factorial(0); -- 1
```

For the T-SQL approach, just make `@BaseNumber = 0` and it will return `1` (no need to copy and paste it again here just for that).

Answer (score 8):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

You may be disappointed with the results in SQL Server compared to PostgreSQL (which is able to deal with very large numbers such as [30000!](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0a9334215eae2296b2a2ca050874a6ad) without loss of precision).

In SQL Server `33!` is as high as you can go with exact precision whilst `170!` is as high as you can go at all ([`171!` is `1.24E309`](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=171%21) which exceeds the limits of `float`).

So you could just precalculate them and store them in a table with values `0 ... 170`. This fits on a single data page if compression is used.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Factorials
  (
     N               TINYINT PRIMARY KEY WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW),
     FactorialExact  NUMERIC(38, 0) NULL,
     FactorialApprox FLOAT NOT NULL
  );

WITH R(N, FactorialExact, FactorialApprox)
     AS (SELECT 0,
                CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(38, 0)),
                1E0
         UNION ALL
         SELECT R.N + 1,
                CASE WHEN R.N < 33 THEN ( R.N + 1 ) * R.FactorialExact END,
                CASE WHEN R.N < 170 THEN ( R.N + 1 ) * R.FactorialApprox END
         FROM   R
         WHERE  R.N < 170)
INSERT INTO dbo.Factorials
            (N,
             FactorialExact,
             FactorialApprox)
SELECT N,
       FactorialExact,
       FactorialApprox
FROM   R
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 170);
```

Alternatively, the following will give accurate results for @N up to 10 - and approximate for 11+ (it would be more accurate if the various functions/constants (`PI()`, `EXP()`, `POWER()`) worked with `DECIMAL` types but they work with `FLOAT` only):

```
DECLARE @N integer = 10;

SELECT
    CONVERT
    (
        DECIMAL(38,0),
        SQRT(2 * PI() * @N) * 
        POWER(@N/EXP(1), @N) * 
        EXP(1.0/12.0/@N + 1.0/360.0/POWER(@N, 3))
    );
```